# Grails security event listener session ID

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have set up an Authentication event listener in grails that implements ApplicationListener. I have code to log failures and successes. Now, for a successful authentication I'm logging the session id, which I'm grabbing like this:

```
RequestContextHolder?.getRequestAttributes()?.getSession().id
```

However, I also want to log the "new" session that the user is being switched to after their successful login. Is there any way to grab that? I know the request still has the "old" session because that's the session used to initiate the login request, so that makes perfect sense. However, I think that the new session has been created already by the time the AuthenticationSuccessEvent has fired, so I would really like to grab this new session id so I can log it as well for a better audit trail, if possible.

Comment: I assume that it's the spring security stuff that's issuing the new session upon logging in, unless that's an incorrect assumption. If it's not spring security that's doing it, then this question is probably nonsensical and it must be some hard-to-find code in our application that's issuing the new session.

Comment: Per [Burt Beckwith's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/160313/burt-beckwith) earlier comment on my incorrect answer, [this](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/sessionFixation.html) may be of interest to you.